# Firefox div > svg mouseover fires OUTSIDE div

Tags: javascript, firefox, html, svg, mouseover

I have a `div` with two `svg`-elements inside, which are shown/hidden when hovering with the mouse. The mouseover event is registered with the `div`.

On Chrome and Safari it works, on FF the SVG sits at a different position and the "hitbox" of the `div` where I can hover, is very large, like 3 times the actual size of the div (checked with Firebug, the div also has width and height set to pixels).

How can it be that the mouseover-event fires at a larger region than the `div` occupies?

```js
    $("#was_arrows").mouseover(function() {
            $('#was_arrows svg#normal').attr("class","hidden");
            $('#was_arrows svg#hover').attr("class","");
    });`
```

```css
    #was_arrows {
        cursor: pointer;
        position:absolute;
        right: 40px;
        top: 23px;
        height: 30px;
        width: 53px;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="was_arrows">
        <svg id="normal">
            <path d="M 5 0 l 0 30 l 15 -15 l -15 -15"/>
            <path d="M 25 0 l 0 30 l 15 -15 l -15 -15"/>
            <path d="M 45 0 l 0 30 l 15 -15 l -15 -15"/>
        </svg>
        <svg id="hover" class="hidden">
            <path d="M 5 0 l 0 30 l 15 -15 l -15 -15"/>
            <path d="M 25 0 l 0 30 l 15 -15 l -15 -15"/>
            <path d="M 45 0 l 0 30 l 15 -15 l -15 -15"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

LINK: http://streuplan.feibra.at/streuplan/index.php?r=streuplan/go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<svg>` elements don't have width and height attributes. This means they become 300 x 150 pixels in size (Chrome doesn't implement this correctly which is why you see the difference). I'm not sure what you want in your case but starting with a width and height of 100% would not be ureasonable.